# rbenv issue: Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.2.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, unicorn, rbenv

I have a problem with setting Ruby version in a unicorn start script. When I run start script in debug mode I have the following output.

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ sudo sh -x /etc/init.d/unicorn start
+ set -e
+ USAGE=Usage: /etc/init.d/unicorn <start|stop|restart|upgrade|rotate|force-stop>
+ USER=vagrant
+ APP_NAME=my_app
+ APP_ROOT=/vagrant
+ RAILS_ENV=production
+ export RBENV_ROOT=/home/vagrant/.rbenv
+ export  PATH=/home/vagrant/.rbenv/bin:/home/vagrant/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
+ SET_RUBY=cd /vagrant && rbenv rehash && rbenv local 2.2.0
+ CMD=cd /vagrant && rbenv rehash && rbenv local 2.2.0;bundle exec unicorn -c config/unicorn.rb -E production -D
+ PID=/vagrant/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid
+ OLD_PID=/vagrant/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid.oldbin
+ cd /vagrant
+ sig 0
+ test -s /vagrant/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid
+ echo Starting my_app
Starting my_app
+ su - vagrant -c cd /vagrant && rbenv rehash && rbenv local 2.2.0;bundle exec unicorn -c config/unicorn.rb -E production -D
-su: rbenv: command not found
Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.2.0
```

I guess the problem is with `su - vagrant -c ...` section. That is originally `su - $USER -m -c "$CMD"`.

How can I fix this? Thank you.

Comment: Is ruby version specified in gem file? show related content from gem file and gemlock file?

Comment: Yes, it is specified as 2.2.0 in Gemfile and it runs well in development environment.

`source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.2.0'
gem 'rails', '4.2.0'
...`

Comment: I think you must change it to 2.2.0 in your terminal session and run server.

Comment: I can change Ruby versions and run server smoothly in a terminal session. I just want it to run in /etc/init.d/unicorn.

Comment: I am not a Linux guy but I think the problem is when I use `su - vagrant $CMD`, it just forgets $PATH and rbenv commands. Unfortunately all examples I have found in the internet use su command with rbenv.