# su - $USER -p -c "$CMD" not accessing path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, shell, unix, su

I am a former Windows guy and I am having trouble with Unix shell.

`su - $USER -p -c "$CMD"` this command like [this one](https://gist.github.com/nebiros/2776085#file-unicorn_application_name-L46) has to access path variables of the given environment but it does not. When I change it to `su - $USER -p -c "export PATH=$PATH; $CMD"`, it works as expected. (I guess).

I am trying this code in an init script and I have another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27888348/rbenv-issue-your-ruby-version-is-1-9-3-but-your-gemfile-specified-2-2-0?noredirect=1#comment44177706_27888348) related to this one. (Sorry for duplication, but I am sure where is the correct place to ask.)

1. First question is why `su - $USER -c $CMD` forgets all previously defined env variables?
2. Is it a correct approach to insert path inside the command like `su - $USER -p -c "export PATH=$PATH; $CMD"`

**Edit**

- `su $USER -p -c "whoami && echo $PATH && $CMD"`, I tried removing `-`. Still not working.
- When I experiment with the following command `su - $USER -p -c "whoami && echo $PATH && $CMD"` I can see that $user and $path are set correctly. But it still cannot find binaries under the $PATH.

**Edit-2**

I made a few more experiments and I have come to shortest working form: `su $USER -c "PATH=$PATH; $CMD"`. I am still not sure if this is the best practise?

Comment: Because `su` intentionally doesn't preserve the environment of the parent. Doing that blindly would be a security issue. There is a `-m`/`-p` flag to preserve the environment but for something like this your solution is probably better (though you probably don't need the `export` bit).

Comment: Thanks for explaining `su` behavior. I edited my question as response to answers. It seems `su` can access the $PATH from inside `-c` but not executables under the $PATH. I guess it is also a security issue. Are you suggesting just inserting the $PATH inside `-c` command as I did.

Comment: If `PATH` inside the `sudo` shell has the path to the binary you are expecting the sudo spawned shell to run then it should be able to find it. What error are you getting exactly?

Comment: `su $USER -c "PATH=$PATH; $CMD` this works as expected. I don't understand why it does not work without assigning path in the command string. The error and output is the same here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27888348/rbenv-issue-your-ruby-version-is-1-9-3-but-your-gemfile-specified-2-2-0?lq=1

Shortly it is a Command Not Found error.

Comment: Do you have custom `PATH` modifications as your current user that you don't for the `su` user? That would explain the issue. What does `su - $USER -c 'echo $PATH'` output? Does it include the path to `rbenv`?

Comment: When you use `su - $USER -c "PATH=$PATH; cmd"` you are setting the value of path in the `su`-spawned shell from the value of `PATH` in the current shell.

Comment: In order to demonstrate init.d, I logged in as root with `su - root` and I executed the command with `sh -x /etc/init.d/unicorn start`. And the output of `su - $USER -c 'echo $PATH'` is:
`/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games`
It seems this is aware of the $PATH in the script and user vagrant's ~/.bashrc.

Comment: And what is the path to `rbenv`?

Comment: I prepared a Gist for your question. I think it gives all the information needed. https://gist.github.com/turhn/561e2dbf405c614f99c1

Comment: You are setting `PATH` in the shell running the init script. Not the su-spawned shell that needs to actually run `rbenv`. That's what `-c "PATH=$PATH; $CMD"` works. Because the shell running init expands `$PATH` into the string passed to `-c` the same as it expands `$CMD`. When you pull that out the su-spawned shell has the default `PATH` which doesn't contain the modified locations.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68686/discussion-between-turhanco-and-etan-reisner).

Answer (score 0):

`su -` means switch user and load the new user's environment (similar to what's loaded when you log in as the user to begin with). Try doing `su` instead without the `-`. This switches user but keeps the environment how it was before you swapped the user.

Answer (score 0):

Well  su - means use a login shell. So it is taking on the env of the user you are su'ing to.   If you want to keep your env omit the -

Comment: I tried with your suggestion and it is still not working. I also edited my question. Please check it out.

Answer (score 0):

`man su`:

> The value of `$PATH` is reset to /bin:/usr/bin for normal users...